# Issue accessing Sesame server and workbench

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, sesame, openrdf

I am trying to access 
localhost/openrdf-workbench/
or
localhost/openrdf-sesame/
but I can't access the webapp. I got the following page:

[image]

[image]

Any help please

Comment: You need to deploy your application. Not change your "DocumentRoot".

Comment: Thanks Elliott Frisch for your feedback, really helpful